# Mongodb aggregate add all fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection recording impressions (views) of certain tags. I want to see the count of each tag value. In the response I also want to see the whole of the record, in the same way that mysql would.

I'm doing a group using the aggregate pipeline which looks like this

```
    db.tag_impressions.aggregate( [
        { $group : { _id : "$tag_value" , count:{$sum:1} } },
        { $sort : { count: 1 } }
    ] )
```

I want to return all of the matched document in tag_impressions.
and I've had some success using $first

```
    db.tag_impressions.aggregate( [
        { $group : { _id : "$tag_value" , "tag_type" : {$first : "Tag_type"} , count:{$sum:1} } },
        { $sort : { count: 1 } }
    ] )
```

But I would have to specify each field and it would take away the benefit from mongo being schema-less.

How can I return all of the document in the results?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Could you be more specific with your question?

Comment: I would suggest you rethink your usage of `$first` here. There is no important information being returned other than the "first" value that occurs, and note there is no sorting here, so that is going to be reasonably random in the real world. Yes there is a simple way to get the whole document. But the way you are doing this, the main thing you should be thinking is "which document?" and also "why?". Results from `$first` would not reall seem to apply to anything useful here.

Comment: The tag_type is the same for each tag_value, $first would return the same as $last or (if it existed) $random.

Comment: edited the description to make it clearer

Comment: In a sense you want [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT). But I still cannot help but feel you are missing the point of what `$first` is returning or meant to do. Most of the "full document" information is not of much use on any sort of aggregation accumulation by nature. Typically you just want the common values that are grouped on.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so whats the correct solution?